# Font family issue in dompdf

Tags: php, codeigniter, fonts, dompdf, google-fonts

I'm using [DOMPDF](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf) v0.8.0

I'm having a problem with this library. I'm using this dompdf library with codeigniter2.

I need to implement digital signature and convert the html into pdf. This signature section have different fonts. I'm using google fonts for signature.

I'd added this font to html

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Herr+Von+Muellerhoff" rel="stylesheet">
```

And added the `font-family` to a particular `<span>` tag.

`<span style='font-family: Herr Von Muellerhoff;'> test sign </span>`

But now I'm getting the whole pdf page in which this `<span>` tag exist having this font family. Remaining pages have default fonts.

I also tried with `<font>` tag but no success

`<font face='Herr Von Muellerhoff'> test sign </font>`

Can anyone help me out from this?

Comment: Can you produce a simplified HTML document that exhibits the issue?

Comment: I'd tried with simple HTML and PHP and it's working fine. I think the issue is with codeigniter + DOMPDF.

Comment: Perhaps. If you can get the actual HTML being passed to dompdf you can try [validating it](http://validator.w3.org/). If that doesn't help paste a sample of it back here.

Comment: I got this message after validating the HTML : `Document checking completed. No errors or warnings to show.` But the pdf problem still there.

Comment: Is the HTML something you can share here?

Comment: Thank you so much for your support. I'd resolved the issue.

Comment: I'd added one more google font in the html and set that `font-family` to body. In my code may be the default font was not working or something like this.

Answer (score 0):

1. get the css with: wget [https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2\?family\=Herr+Von+Muellerhoff:wght@300\;400\;700](https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2%5C?family%5C=Herr+Von+Muellerhoff:wght@300%5C;400%5C;700) and you get:

   @font-face {
   font-family: 'Herr Von Muellerhoff';
   font-style: normal;
   font-weight: 400;
   src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/herrvonmuellerhoff/v13/WBL6rFjRZkREW8WqmCWYLgCkQKXb4CAft3c6.ttf) format('truetype');
   }

2 Add css to your dompdf template

3 get zip font file from google fonts : https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Herr+Von+Muellerhoff (click on download family button) and copy the content zip file to your storage/fonts on your laravel directory

4. Enjoy